# Problema ao ordenar posts no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, framework, order

Olá, bom dia.

Galera, tô com problema ao ordenar posts nas categorias do wordpress.

Ex: Tenho a categoria notícias, filmes, músicas, imagens.. Quero ordenar os posts dessas categorias na ordem crescente. Usei o seguinte código

```
<?php query_posts("order=ASC"); ?>
```

Mas ao invés de mostrar apenas os posts atrelados a categoria, ele puxa todos os posts do site.

Usei também

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'post','orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC');
```

Ocorreu o mesmo problema, ao invés de listar os posts da categoria na ordem crescente, ele lista todos os posts.

O código completo da `category.php` é esse:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <header class="container">
    <?php
        the_archive_title( '<h1 class="text-center">', '</h1>' );
        the_archive_description( '<h4 class="text-center">', '</h4>' );
            ?>
    </header><!-- .page-header -->

<section class="categorias">
    <div class="container">
    <?php  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
        <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'reservado', true) == 'no'): ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">
                <?php the_title();?>
                </a>
            </h3>
            <?php echo odin_thumbnail(400, 200, true, 'minha-classe' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><?php echo paginate_links(); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
<?php else:?>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Não existem pontos nesta semana</h1>
        <img src="/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

[Código no pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3cuWE44f)

Desde já, agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Leo, você quer ordenar crescente pela data ou pelo título do post?

Comment: Olá, Giovanni. 

Preciso alinhar pelo título, e que ele liste apenas os posts da categoria atrelada ao post, e não aleatório.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguinte Leo, partindo da premissa que esse seu código esteja funcionando, irei aproveitá-lo  para facilitar. Adicionei `query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title' );` para adicionar uma ordenação por titulo na query já existente.

Da uma olhada no código abaixo:

```
<?php 
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title' );
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<header class="container">
    <?php
    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="text-center">', '</h1>' );
    the_archive_description( '<h4 class="text-center">', '</h4>' );
    ?>
</header><!-- .page-header -->

<section class="categorias">
    <div class="container">
        <?php  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
            <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'reservado', true) == 'no'): ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">
                            <?php the_title();?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <?php echo odin_thumbnail(400, 200, true, 'minha-classe' ); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="text-center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><?php echo paginate_links(); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else:?>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1>Não existem pontos nesta semana</h1>
            <img src="/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</section>
```

Código também disponível no [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/M2a4PQRa)

**Explicação**

Quando você tentou usar `<?php query_posts("order=ASC"); ?>` você estava substituindo a query_posts para `order=ASC` então estava trazendo tudo ordenado por data.

Usando o `query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=title' );` você está concatenando a `query_posts` junto a o orderby.

Comment: Aparentemente deu certo, Giovanni. Só não entendi direito, por que do 36 pulou para o 57 e depois 36.

Seria por causa da ordem das letras? Todos os posts começam com números 1 - Rua Brasil, 2 - Rua Matilda, 3 - Rua Amaral...

http://prntscr.com/cne0g9

Comment: @Leonardo realmente é estranho, tenta rodar essa query no seu banco de dados `SELECT 'post_title' FROM 'wp_posts' ORDER BY 'post_title'
` Pode ser que não seja `wp_posts` ai para você caso tenha mudado

Comment: Caso ele retorne errado também no banco, ai seria o caso de dar uma pesquisada, pois nunca aconteceu comigo isso. Mas verifica se nas próximas páginas ele também esta invertendo o ultimo com o penúltimo!

Comment: Deu erro no banco, igual você disse, eu também não entendi o que tá pegando, mas mesmo assim obrigado, Giovanni, o avanço foi grande.

Comment: @Leonardo Nada não pô! Mas caso precise de ajuda para entender essa maracutaia ai do SQL, aconselho a criar uma pergunta nova só para tratar disso!! Caso eu tenha ajudado e a duvida dessa pergunta esteja concluída, me avalie positivamente e marque o "check" na minha resposta!

Comment: Pode deixar, Giovanni. Vou dar uma estudada mais afundo. Ajudou muito, obrigado pela força.